# Jenkins P4 plugin triggers, trigger by branch

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am using the "P4 Plugin" - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin in Jenkins v2.32.1.

I would like to trigger specific jobs in Jenkins, depending on what path is changed in SCM.

For example if something changes in

```
//depot/branchA
```

Build job A. If something changes in

```
//depot/branchB
```

Build job B.

As far as I can tell the plugin is only set up to trigger every job in Jenkins that has "Perforce triggered build." (building both A and B jobs) Am I missing something? I am currently using SCM polling and trying to move to a more efficient system.

This understanding is based on reading the "Triggering" section of https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/SETUP.md

Answer (score 1):

You may be defining too broad a workspace, and causing Jenkins to trigger on every submit. The client workspace associated with job A should only map //depot/branchA/..., and the workspace for job B should only map //depot/branchB/....

Jenkins polls for changes, and if it sees any, triggers any build that has a matching path. So if both jobs had a workspace that mapped //depot/... then submits to branchA or branchB would trigger both jobs.